# Navigation menu displays permalinks

Tags: menus, permalinks, navigation

I am creating a theme from scratch and the navigation menu is disturbing
me because it is displaying the permalinks after the menu item name. See this 
picture

http://imagebin.org/212406

Link name (#permalink) is the result of 
`wp_nav_menu()`

Setting e.g.
`$before/$after` - yields text before/after (#permalink)

The (#permalink) part is not displayed in the source.

Since it's only Pages I tried wp_list_pages(), but that gives me the same result.

Any ideas on how to remove those permalinks? I believe there is some 'default' setting for how links/menu items should be displayed but I don't know where to look.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the (#url) isn't displayed in the source, I suspect this is being placed there by CSS with a rule like:

```
#menu a:after { content: "#"attr(href); }
```

If I had to guess it's a print stylesheet run amok, possibly from a plugin.

Comment: Yes you're right. As a matter of fact, all links have that "bug". How come?

Comment: It's a theming or plugin issue. Use a tool like Firebug to track down which style sheet it's in and then work backwards from there. Like I said, it's a common thing in Print stylesheets, so if you have a plugin that does that, I'm guessing it's the culprit.

Comment: If you send me a link, I can track it down very quickly.